# Singleton services are not available to lazy loaded modules

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular2-services

I recently split my single `AppModule` into multiple modules and now I am attempting to lazy-load a module and make it use singleton services from a shared module.

I followed the steps mentioned [in the docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#core-for-root) (as well as [in this tutorial](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/shared-di-tree.html)) and created a shared `CoreModule` that provides singleton services. However, when one of the shared module's services is trying to inject any of the singleton services, the following exception is thrown:

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for HttpClientService!
Error: No provider for HttpClientService!
    at NoProviderError.BaseError [as constructor] (http://localhost:5000/lib/angular/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:1105:38)
```

**`app.module.ts`**

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        CoreModule.forRoot(),
        AppRoutingModule
    ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**`app-routing.module.ts`**

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "mailgroups",
        loadChildren: "app/mailgroup/mailgroup.module#MailGroupModule"  // <-- lazy loading the module
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
    exports: [ RouterModule ],
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**`core.module.ts`** (shared module)

```
export class CoreModule {
    constructor (@Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule: CoreModule) {
        if (parentModule) {
            throw new Error("CoreModule is already loaded. Import it in the AppModule only!");
        }
    }

    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: CoreModule,
            providers: [
                HttpClientService,  // <-- singleton service 1
                UserService         // <-- singleton service 2
            ]
        };
    }
}
```

**`mailgroup.module.ts`** (lazy loaded module)

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        MailGroupRoutingModule
    ]
})
export class MailGroupModule { }
```

What's interesting, is that when I import the shared module `CoreModule` to the lazy-loaded module `MailGroupModule`, I don't get any exception (despite the `throw new Error(...)` in the constructor), because the `parentModule` argument is always `null`.

Am I missing something obvious here? (left out declarations that I deemed unnecessary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many hours of programming "at random", while pulling my hair out, my efforts paid off. The issue was in a malconfigured **`system.config.js`**.

When comparing SystemJS configuration to [the `systemjs.config.web.js` used in the docs](https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular/angular.io/b3c65a9/public/docs/_examples/_boilerplate/systemjs.config.web.js), I noticed subtle differences in the way the app folder and the path to the file that bootstraps the app are configured in my file.

**✘ Before** (Malconfigured SystemJS)

```
System.config({
    paths: { ... },
    map: {
        app: '/app',                // <-- This line (incorrect)
        ...
    },
    packages: {
        app: {
            main: '/main.js'        // <-- And this line (incorrect)
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
    }
})
```

Notice the leading slash in the `app: '/app'` and a relative path in `main: '/main.js'`.

**✔ After** (Correct SystemJS configuration)
(changed to `app: 'app'` and `main: './main.js'`)

```
System.config({
    paths: { ... },
    map: {
        app: 'app',                 // <-- This line (correct)
        ...
    },
    packages: {
        app: {
            main: './main.js'       // <-- And this line (correct)
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
    }
})
```

So, these two subtle fixes made all the difference in the world!

Now, too, trying to import the shared module `CoreModule` anywhere else but `AppModule`, results in an exception being thrown, as expected.

Answer (score 1):

according to best practice, the CoreModule is an extension to the AppModule. it shouldn't be a shared module. it should only be imported and used by the AppModule
a shared module, should be called..... SharedModule